# installing ensime via using el-get was failed

Tags: java, macos, scala, emacs, elisp

I using emacs and el-get package management system.
I tried to install ensime via el-get but it was failed.

Warning buffer show following message.

> Warning (emacs): Build command "sbt update stage" in package "ensime"
>   will be shell-interpolated. To bypass shell interpolation, the recipe
>   for "ensime" should specify build commands as lists of strings
>   instead.

Here is my environment.

- Max OS X Lion (10.7.4)
- Cocoa Emacs(XEmacs) 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1138.47)
- el-get.el version 4.0
- el-get ensime recipe ( https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/blob/112a6c2e388ac47f878cff9933af5b931b0d318e/recipes/ensime.rcp )
- Scala version 2.9.2
- Java version "1.6.0_31"

Comment: Can Emacs find `sbt` if you run it from Emacs?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I think el-get run sbt through bash because Message buffer show message that 'el-get is waiting for "/bin/bash" to complete'. and I tried to run sbt command in the OS X Terminal(bash), it was completed with no errors.

Comment: btw, what is in the `*Messages*` buffer. On my Mac OS X 10.6, ensime wasn't compiled because lack of memory...

Comment: It happened to me too. I thought it needs more PermSize so I create ~/.sbtconfig file and wrote following line. 'SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"'. sbt reads ~/.sbtconfig and use $SBT_OPTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think that I found problem - package itself is installed correctly, but `load-path` is incorrectly set in receipe. Change string in `:load-path` from `./dist/elisp` to `./src/main/elisp`, and it should work.
If it will work, then I'll commit change to repository

Comment: Sorry, It happend because of OutOfMemoryError. When I set MaxPermSize to 1024M, sbt command finished normaly. And after that, like you said, load-path error happend. I fix local recipe and try again to install. thanks.

Comment: I fixed load-path and the install succeeded. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I pushed change into repository & will create a ticket so recipe should work out of box

Comment: Thanks! I'll enjoy Scala programming.